# Laravel Forge Seeding

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-forge

I would like some help with seeding my database, using Laravel Forge.
I've carried out the deployment for my application and it was successful. The tables were created, as my latest deployment log shows:

From github.com:nahin14/cin-app
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes
Migrated: 2014_10_11_000000_create_roles_table
Migrated: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated: 2015_04_16_205049_create_statuses_table
Migrated: 2015_04_16_205103_create_claim_types_table
Migrated: 2015_04_16_205118_create_insurance_types_table
Migrated: 2015_04_16_205127_create_insurers_table
Migrated: 2015_04_16_205215_create_solicitors_table
Migrated: 2015_04_16_205224_create_client_types_table
Migrated: 2015_04_16_205229_create_clients_table
Migrated: 2015_04_16_205243_create_vehicle_types_table
Migrated: 2015_04_16_205251_create_vehicles_table
Migrated: 2015_04_16_205312_create_claims_table
Migrated: 2015_04_16_205318_create_tasks_table

However i would like to know how i can seed the tables. I have a databaseseeder.php file set up with all the seeding information.
So, how would i go about seeding the tables with the seeding information from the databaseseeder.php file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

There is a force for production, similar as on the migrate command:

```
php artisan db:seed --force
```

But for shure, take care with this...

You can look at the options of every artisan command with the help command, ex

```
php artisan help db:seed
```

Comment: I was looking for this for a long time. I was missing the `--force` option. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

php artisan db:seed

or

php artisan db:seed --class="TheOneSeeder"

Comment: Thanks, but I tried entering the command into forge's deployment script for the application, but it did not work.

Comment: So, this is what my deployment script in forge looks like now:

cd /home/forge/default
git pull origin master
composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist
php artisan migrate --force
php artisan db:seed

It simply did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the value for APP_ENV in your environment settings (.env file) is set to something other than production - staging, local, etc ...

You can navigate to this by going to Sites->Your Site->Environment->Edit Environment.

For the deploy script:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=TheOneSeeder
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan db:seed --force` worked on forge
You can do that from forge -> Commands
[image: (example)]

Note : The following didn't work on forge:

`php artisan db:seed`
or
`php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder`